# php REQUEST_URI

Tags: php

I have the following php script to read the request in URL :

```
$id = '/' != ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? 
    str_replace('/?id=' ,"", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) : 0;
```

It was used when the URL is `http://www.testing.com/?id=123`

But now I wanna pass 1 more variable in url string `http://www.testing.com/?id=123&othervar=123`

how should I change the code above to retrieve both variable?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can either use regex, or keep on using `str_replace`.

Eg.

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if ($url != '/') {
    parse_str($url['query']);
    echo $id;
    echo $othervar;
}
```

Output will be: 
http://www.testing.com/123/123

Comment: Beat me to it! Also, consider using $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] to simplify.

Comment: so it would be something like
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ($url != '/') {
    $id = str_replace('/?id=', null, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $othervar = str_replace('&othervar=', '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
echo $id //123
echo $othervar //123

Comment: I'd also consider using pattern matching.

Comment: @user1118904 No, I'd suggest you strip the domain and trailing directories from the URL, and then perform the script provided on it. I updated my post.

Comment: @user1118904, Oldskool's method is simpler though.

Answer (score 5):

I think that [**parse_str**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) is what you're looking for, something like this should do the trick for you:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $vars);
```

Then the `$vars` array will hold all the passed arguments.

Comment: @balping No, it is not. Quoting the manual: `Using this function without the result parameter is highly DISCOURAGED and DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.` So using it without the result parameter (the second parameter) is deprecated. This is an optional parameter, but will become mandatory in future versions.

Comment: @Oldskool Sorry, you're right, I removed the misinformation

Answer (score 1):

perhaps

```
$id = isset($_GET['id'])?$_GET['id']:null;
```

and

```
$other_var = isset($_GET['othervar'])?$_GET['othervar']:null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `$_GET`
especially if you know the `othervar`'s name.
If you want to be on the safe side, use `if (isset ($_GET ['varname']))`
to test for existence.

Answer (score 1):

```php
$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since vars passed through url are $_GET vars, you can use `filter_input()` function:

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$othervar = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'othervar', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

It would store the values of each var and sanitize/validate them too.